# How can i use the filters and other functions in weka in python?

Tags: weka, python-3.10

i copied a piece of code : from weka.core.filters import Filter
it comes from EDUCBA
[image]

it seems tha it can use the filters from weka in python
but when run it it always gets something wrong
it told me that: Unresolved reference 'Filter'
how can i deal with it?

Comment: Did you install the python-weka-wrapper3 library?

Comment: i didn't ,but i ' m gonna try it,thanks

Comment: Follow the instructions: https://github.com/fracpete/python-weka-wrapper3

Comment: Thanks ,I have solved this problem,and I successfully ran a part of the code from the instructions that you give me.But i got a new question now,And i posted it just now,could you help me about that

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.